# Android - Choosing a method to run in a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java-threads, android-threading

I'm creating an Android app that communicates with a webservice.

I have a SOAP class that holds different methods which execute web service functions and a SOAPCaller class that runs a thread to call the methods within the SOAP class.

To choose which method is called by the thread in SOAPCaller, I am setting a string with the name of the method from where ever in my app, my run() method then has a switch statement which looks at the string to decide which method from SOAP should be called.

This is working fine but just feels very hacky... is there a better way of doing this? Can I just call the desired method within my SOAPCaller class when the thread runs somehow?

Any help or advice appreciated. Thanks!

**HomeFragment**

```
public void Addition()
    {
        try {

            //get values from ui
            int valueA = Integer.parseInt(etIntA.getText().toString());
            int valueB = Integer.parseInt(etIntB.getText().toString());

            //new soap caller
            SOAPCaller soapCaller = new SOAPCaller();
            //set method (this is how I tell the thread which method to run)
            soapCaller.setMethod("Addition");
            //set the values to be used by the addition method
            soapCaller.setAdditionValues(valueA, valueB);
            //start the thread
            soapCaller.setStartThread(true);
            //start soap caller thread
            soapCaller.join();
            soapCaller.start();

            //loop until result is updated
            while (soapCaller.getStartThread()) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {

                }
            }

            //show the result on screen
            tvResult.setText(soapCaller.getResult());

        }
        catch(Exception ex) {

            //show error on screen
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

**SOAPCaller:**

```
private String method;
private String result;

public void run() {

    try {

        //new soap actions class
        soap = new SOAP();

        switch (method) {

            case "Addition":
                //call addition action, pass given values and get the result
                result = soap.Addition(additionA, additionB);
                startThread = false;
                break;

            case "InsertEmployee":
                //pass values and insert new employee into database
                result = soap.InsertEmployee(insertName, insertDob, insertRole);
                startThread = false;
                break;

            case "SelectEmployee":
                //pass values and insert new employee into database
                result = soap.SelectEmployee(selectEmployeeName);
                startThread = false;
                break;

            case "ConnectionTest":
                //test the webservice connection
                result = soap.ConnectionTest();
                startThread = false;
                break;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //error occurred
        result = ex.toString();
    }
}
```

**SOAP**

```
 public String Addition(int a, int b) {

     //new request and property
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME_ADDITION);
     PropertyInfo propertyInfo;

     //add integer a into property info
     propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
     propertyInfo.setName("valueA");
     propertyInfo.setValue(a);
     propertyInfo.setType(Integer.class);
     request.addProperty(propertyInfo);

     //add integer b into property info
     propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
     propertyInfo.setName("valueB");
     propertyInfo.setValue(b);
     propertyInfo.setType(Integer.class);
     request.addProperty(propertyInfo);

     //new soap serialisation envelope
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     envelope.dotNet = true;

     //set http transport as webservice address
     HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

     //object to hold result
     Object response = null;

     try {

         //call SOAP action and get response
         httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION_ADDITION, envelope);
         response = envelope.getResponse();
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {

         //get error
         response = ex.toString();
     }

     //return result
     return response.toString();
 }
```